# Android library dependencies

Tags: java, android, dependencies, android-volley, android-library

I'm doing an android library project.
The library project has compile some 3rd party library such as Volley.
When user use the library, user need to compile the volley too. If user do not compile, the app of user will not find the volley code.
But I don't want to the user compile volley library, just compile my library. Is there a solution to solve???

There is my library gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup:seismic:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1"
    compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1"
    compile "com.android.support:design:23.0.1"
}
```

There is a sample app gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 108
        versionName "3.1"

    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("debug.jks")
            storePassword 'develop'
            keyAlias "develop"
            keyPassword "develop"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
        abortOnError false
    }
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2'
    compile 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.6.0'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.getkeepsafe.taptargetview:taptargetview:1.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup:seismic:1.0.1'<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< I need to hide this
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< I need to hide this
    compile project(':mylibrary')

}
```

Comment: You can just remove this lines...

Comment: But if user remove this line, the app cannot find the volley library and will be crashed

Comment: Have you read https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html completely?

Comment: I read it now . thank you for your help